# How to force log compaction of a Kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

Using Kafka 2.7.0 (in K8s), I create a test topic with `cleanup.policy=compact`:

```sh
./kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 --topic _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 3 --config cleanup.policy=compact
```

Write some messages to it:

```sh
kafkacat -b kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -P -t _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 -K:
1:a
2:b
3:c
1:d
2:e
```

Change the topic settings in a way such that compaction should kick in after 10 seconds:

```sh
./kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper zookeeper.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local --topic _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 --config max.compaction.lag.ms=10000 --config min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.0 --config segment.ms=10000 --config delete.retention.ms=10000
```

Wait a minute, just to be sure:

```sh
sleep 60
```

Check the topic content:

```sh
kafkacat -C -e -o beginning -b kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 -K:
```

And to my surprise, the content is still

```
1:a
2:b
3:c
1:d
2:e
```

instead of the

```
3:c
1:d
2:e
```

which I expected.

Why is the topic not compacted, and what can I do to force it?

Comment: I don't think altering segment.ms retroactively changes existing segments, so you'd need to create the topic with that, produce data, then wait the 10 seconds

Comment: @OneCricketeer Ah, that makes sense. Thanks! It also helped me find a way to force compaction of the old segments. After changing the settings, I just needed to produce another message to the topics, which, I guess, creates a new segment, making the old ones eligible for compaction. This way it works as I intended to. :)

Comment: Cool. Feel free to put those steps as an answer below

Comment: Active segment is not eligible for compaction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since active segments are not eligible for compaction, the trick was to again write something to the topic to force the creation of a new segment.

```sh
# Create a test topic.
./kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 --topic _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 3 --config cleanup.policy=compact

# Write some messages to it.
echo "1:a\n2:b\n3:c" | kafkacat -b kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -P -t _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 -K:

# Check the topic content.
kafkacat -C -e -o beginning -b kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 -K:

# Change the topic settings in a way such that compaction should kick in after 10 seconds.
./kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper zookeeper.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local --topic _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 --config max.compaction.lag.ms=10000 --config min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.0 --config segment.ms=10000 --config delete.retention.ms=10000

# Wait for the last segment to outdate
sleep 11

# Write new messages.
echo "1:d\n2:e" | kafkacat -b kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -P -t _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 -K:

# Check the topic content.
kafkacat -C -e -o beginning -b kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 -K:

# Wait for this segment to outdate.
sleep 11

# Write new messages again.
echo "1:d\n2:e" | kafkacat -b kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -P -t _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 -K:

# Check the topic content.
kafkacat -C -e -o beginning -b kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 -K:

# Wait for compaction to happen.
sleep 11

# Check the topic content to validate that it has been compacted.
kafkacat -C -e -o beginning -b kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 -K:

# Revert the setting changes.
./kafka-topics.sh --alter --zookeeper zookeeper.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local --topic _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02 --delete-config max.compaction.lag.ms --delete-config min.cleanable.dirty.ratio --delete-config segment.ms --delete-config delete.retention.ms

# Delete the topic
# /home/th/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --delete --bootstrap-server kafka.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 --topic _test_quick_compaction_2021_12_02
```